# How do I remove newlines from a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell, sed

I have the following data, and I need to put it all into one line.

I have this:

```
22791

;

14336

;

22821

;

34653

;

21491

;

25522

;

33238

;
```

I need this:

```
22791;14336;22821;34653;21491;25522;33238;
```

---

## EDIT

None of these commands is working perfectly.

Most of them let the data look like this:

```
22791

;14336

;22821

;34653

;21491

;25522
```

Comment: Copy-paste into the browser's address bar or another text field. Quick'n'dirty but works for small amounts of data.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

```
tr --delete '\n' < yourfile.txt
tr -d '\n' < yourfile.txt
```

If none of the commands posted here are working, then you have something other than a newline separating your fields. Possibly you have DOS/Windows line endings in the file (although I would expect the Perl solutions to work even in that case)?

Try:

```
tr -d "\n\r" < yourfile.txt
```

If that doesn't work then you're going to have to inspect your file more closely (e.g., in a hex editor) to find out what characters are actually in there that you want to remove.

Comment: How do you write this output to the same or another file?

Comment: I think `tr` is not suitable for empty lines. What do you think? - - I think `sed` is the best option like described here http://stackoverflow.com/q/16414410/54964

Comment: To route the output to another file just use output redirection. To route it to the same file pipe it to "sponge" (available in the "moreutils" package on Debian base systems).

Comment: To write the output to the same file, use a subshell `echo -n $(tr -d "\n" < yourfile.txt) > yourfile.txt`

Comment: @andpei Thanks very much for that and here is a simple shell script that takes the file name ($1) and does the same work:
echo -n $(tr -d "\n" < $1) > $1
Put it in a removeNL.sh file & chmod 777 and run it $ ./removeNL yourfile.txt

Answer (score 23):

```
tr -d '\n' < file.txt
```

Or

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $0 }' file.txt
```

Or

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' file.txt
```

This page [here](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/rmnl-remove-new-line-characters-tr-awk-perl-sed-c-cpp-bash-python-xargs-ghc-ghci-haskell-sam-ssam-p65/) has a bunch of other methods to remove newlines.

Answer (score 14):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\R//g;' filename
```

Must do the job.

Comment: Golfs to `perl -pie 's/\R//g' filename`

Comment: No, the `-i` takes an argument, so it can't be smushed up to `-e`: `perl -i -pe ...`

Answer (score 12):

Expanding on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3134827/5362795), this removes all new lines and saves the result to a new file (thanks to @tripleee):

```
tr -d '\n' < yourfile.txt > yourfile2.txt
```

Which is better than a "useless cat" (see comments):

```
cat file.txt | tr -d '\n' > file2.txt
```

Also useful for getting rid of new lines at the end of the file, e.g., created by using `echo blah > file.txt`.

Note that the destination filename is different, important, otherwise you'll wipe out the original content!

Comment: That's a [useless `cat.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)  Several comment threads here already explain how to redirect the result to a new file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I just saw a comment with `echo -n $(tr -d "\n" < yourfile.txt) > yourfile.txt` but hadn't seen it before.

Comment: That's even more convoluted, with the well-known portability issues around `echo -n`. The simple obvious idiomatic way to do that is `tr -d '\n' <file.txt >file2.txt`

Comment: We need to pay attention to not use the same filename for reading and writing, otherwise the file will be empty.

Answer (score 11):

```
paste -sd "" file.txt
```

Comment: On Solaris (10) `paste -sd ""` doesn't work on STDIN by default, so if you're piping to it, use: 
`(some command) | paste -sd "" -`

Comment: This does not work if you also want to remove the *final* newline. It only removes intermediate newlines.

Comment: This didn't work on Mac OS, Sundeep's version did. `paste -sd'\0' -`

Answer (score 7):

You can edit the file in vim:

```
$ vim inputfile
:%s/\n//g
```

Comment: and to replace with with spaces : `:%s/\n/ /g`

Comment: This worked the best for me.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
head -n 1 filename | od -c
```

to figure *what* the offending character is.

Then use

```
tr -d '\n' <filename
```

for LF, and

```
tr -d '\r\n' <filename
```

for CRLF.

Answer (score 4):

## Use sed with [POSIX classes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions)

This will remove all lines containing only whitespace (spaces & tabs)

#### `sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'`

Just take whatever you are working with and pipe it to that

#### Example

#### `cat filename | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'`

Comment: sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' filename ...for in place editing; answer as above will output to the screen

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same case today. It is super easy in [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) or [Neovim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Neovim), and you can use `gJ` to join lines. For your use case, just do

```
99gJ
```

This will join all your 99 lines. You can adjust the number `99` as needed according to how many lines to join. If just joining **one** line, then only `gJ` is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Using man 1 ed:

```
# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php?id=howto:edit-ed 
ed -s file <<< $'1,$j\n,p'  # print to stdout 
ed -s file <<< $'1,$j\nwq'  # in-place edit
```

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` consumes newlines as well (but adds a final trailing newline):

```
xargs < file.txt | tr -d ' '
```

Answer (score 2):

Nerd fact: use ASCII instead.

```
tr -d '\012' < filename.extension
```

(Edited cause i didn't see the friggin' answer that had same solution, only difference was that mine had ASCII)

Answer (score 2):

Using the gedit text editor (3.18.3)

1. Click **Search**
2. Click **Find and Replace...**
3. Enter `\n\s` into **Find** field
4. Leave **Replace with** blank (nothing)
5. Check **Regular expression** box
6. Click the **Find** button

Note: this doesn't exactly address the OP's original, 7 year old problem but should help some noob linux users (like me) who find their way here from the SE's with similar "how do I get my text all on one line" questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n+//g' input >output
```

```
perl -0777 -pe 'tr/\n//d' input >output
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in file.txt, then:

```
echo $(<file.txt) | tr -d ' '
```

The '`$(<file.txt)`' reads the file and gives the contents as a series of words which 'echo' then echoes with a space between them.  The 'tr' command then deletes any spaces:

```
22791;14336;22821;34653;21491;25522;33238;
```

Comment: This works as long as the input is not too big and as long as you're using Bash (tagged for Bash, so that's OK).  Were I writing the answer now, it would be `tr -d '\n' < file.txt`, which is what the accepted answer does (and I'm surprised I didn't write it at the time).  This was probably just written to show 'yet another way to do it'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to keep the digits and the semicolons, the following should do the trick assuming there are no major encoding issues, though it will also remove the very last "newline":

```
tr -cd ";0-9"
```

You can easily modify the above to include other characters, e.g. if you want to retain decimal points, commas, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I usually get this use case when I'm copying a code snippet from a file and I want to paste it into a console without adding unnecessary new lines, I ended up doing a Bash alias (I called it `oneline` if you are curious)

```
xsel -b -o | tr -d '\n' | tr -s ' ' | xsel -b -i
```

- `xsel -b -o` reads my clipboard
- `tr -d '\n'` removes new lines
- `tr -s ' '` removes recurring spaces
- `xsel -b -i` pushes this back to my clipboard

after that I would paste the new contents of the clipboard into one line in a console or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with awk, e.g.

```
awk '/[0-9]+/ { a = a $0 ";" } END { print a }' file.txt
```

(a disadvantage is that a is "accumulated" in memory).

EDIT

Forgot about printf! So also

```
awk '/[0-9]+/ { printf "%s;", $0 }' file.txt
```

or likely better, what it was already given in the other ans using awk.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the most obvious and fast answer especially when you need to do this in GUI in order to fix some weird word-wrap.

- Open `gedit`
- Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, then put in the `Find` textbox `\n` and in `Replace with` an empty space   then fill checkbox `Regular expression` and voila.

Answer (score -1):

To also remove the trailing newline at the end of the file

```
python -c "s=open('filename','r').read();open('filename', 'w').write(s.replace('\n',''))"
```

Comment: The tags suggest the OP is looking for a shell-based solution. (FWIW, I personally understand the appeal of Python for these use cases)

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way I found:

1. open [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) by doing this in your command line
2. `vim inputfile`
3. press ":" and input the following command to remove all newlines
4. `:%s/\n//g`
5. Input this to also remove spaces in case some characters were spaces `:%s/ //g`
6. make sure to save by writing to the file with
7. `:w`

The same format can be used to remove any other characters, and you can use a website like

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect

to figure out what character you're missing.

You can also use this to figure out other characters you can't see and they have a tool as well.

[Tool to learn of other invisible characters](https://invisible-characters.com/)

Comment: Original question has the `sed` tag; needs a way for automating work, not to do that by hand