# Linux: make output into one line

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am running geoiplookup command on linux, which gives the following:

```
[root@localhost temp]$ geoiplookup 8.8.8.8

GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: US, N/A, N/A, N/A, 38.000000, -97.000000, 0, 0
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 0: US, N/A, N/A, N/A, 38.000000, -97.000000
GeoIP ASNum Edition: AS15169 Google Inc.
```

I want the output to be on one line and have tried this:

```
[root@localhost temp]$ geoiplookup 8.8.8.8 | sed '2,3d' | sed 's/^.*: /,/g' | sed '$!{:a;N;s/\n/\t/;ta}' | awk -F ',' '{print $4","$2}'
AS15169 Google Inc.,US
```

Sorry to make you misunderstand. I want to use easier way to keep the country code and ASNum as the output line.

Like thie "AS15169 Google Inc.,US"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
geoiplookup 8.8.8.8 | awk '/^GeoIP Country/{ sub(/,*$/, "", $4); c = $4; } sub(/^GeoIP ASNum Edition: /, ""){ print $0 "," c }'
```

Expected output:

```
AS15169 Google Inc.,US
```

Edit: `sub` is enough. No need to go `gsub`.

Comment: that works great. Thanks for you answer, learn more thing about awk as well

Comment: @Tazugan Welcome :) You can also consider reading the user's guide if you're using GNU awk: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html.

Answer (score 1):

The paste command will do what you want.

```
geoiplookup 8.8.8.8 | paste -sd " "
```

See also [How do I remove newlines from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
geoiplookup 8.8.8.8 | sed '2,3d' | sed 's/^.*: /,/g' | sed '$!{:a;N;s/\n/\t/;ta}' | awk -F ',' '{print $8","$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple technique is:

```
echo $(geoiplookup 8.8.8.8)
```

Note the absence of double quotes around the `$(…)` command substitution — contrast with [Capturing multiple line output to a `bash` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-to-a-bash-variable/613580#613580).