# How do I remove the line break from alternate lines in an ASCII file

Tags: awk, sed

I have an ASCII file that contains data as follows

```
    459999XXX9998882      WTD CCD           3,500.00-         0.00         3,500.00-         0.00       0.00
       09/07/17  23:00:07   999999999999 000000000000 EONCO024 GTUR BR              AND PARDES  APIN
    459999XXX9998883      WTD CCD             400.00-         0.00           400.00-         0.00       0.00
       09/07/17  23:00:12   999999999999 000000000000 EOMCO015 P.G ROAD, ANNA HOT SECU  TLIN
    29999XXX99988829      INQ CCD               0.00          0.00             0.00          0.00       0.00
       09/07/17  23:00:41   999999999999 000000000000 EOMCO010 PUNA KUMBHARIA ROAD,   SUR        GJIN
    5459999XXX999888   INQ SAV               0.00          0.00             0.00          0.00       0.00    UNABLE TO PROC
       09/07/17  23:00:44   999999999999 000000000000 EONCO089 CTS NO 3985/5 ST STAND SOL      MHIN
```

I would like lines containing the dates to be contactenated to the line above it. Essenatilly I would like to remove all the line breaks from odd numbered lines. So the result is something like this

```
459999XXX9998882      WTD CCD           3,500.00-         0.00         3,500.00-         0.00       0.00 09/07/17  23:00:07   999999999999 000000000000 EONCO024 GTUR BR              AND PARDES  APIN
459999XXX9998883      WTD CCD             400.00-         0.00           400.00-         0.00       0.00 09/07/17  23:00:12   999999999999 000000000000 EOMCO015 P.G ROAD, ANNA HOT SECU  TLIN
29999XXX99988829      INQ CCD               0.00          0.00             0.00          0.00       0.00 09/07/17  23:00:41   999999999999 000000000000 EOMCO010 PUNA KUMBHARIA ROAD,   SUR        GJIN
5459999XXX999888      INQ SAV               0.00          0.00             0.00          0.00       0.00    UNABLE TO PROC 09/07/17  23:00:44   999999999999 000000000000 EONCO089 CTS NO 3985/5 ST STAND SOL      MHIN
```

I tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file) but then it removed all the linebreaks resulting in one single line! Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge every two lines into one from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/how-to-merge-every-two-lines-into-one-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' ip.txt
```

- `N` add next line to pattern space
- `s/\n/ /` change first newline character to space (or whatever is the separator)
- Usage of `\n` might depend on `sed` implementation. This was tested on `GNU sed`

With `perl`, change newline character if line number is odd

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ / if $.%2' ip.txt
```

Can also use

```
xargs -d'\n' -n2 -a ip.txt
```

- `-d'\n'`  newline character as delimiter
- `-n2` two lines together as argument (space is used to combine them)

Comment: You might additionally want to pipe that to `column -t`

Comment: @hek2mgl good point, but not sure if OP's data is tab delimited and whether `AND PARDES  APIN` is single or multiple column..

Comment: Yes, it depends.

Answer (score 2):

Print each line, alternating between a tab and a newline as the Output Record Separator `ORS`:

```
awk '{ ORS = NR % 2 ? "\t" : "\n" } 1' file
```

`NR` is the current record (line) number, so `NR % 2` is true on odd-numbered lines.

Obviously, the tab `"\t"` can be changed to whatever you want to put between the lines that you're joining together.

Comment: This command adds a tab to every 3rd, 6th , 9th rows. It seems to be indenting these lines with the TAB.

Comment: I don't see why it would do anything every 3 rows - if there are already tabs at the start of your even-numbered lines, then you should change `"\t"` to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { printf $0; getline; print $0 }' filename
```

Which means "for every odd line print it without '\n', get next line, print it with '\n'".