# How can I put a line in front of another with sed?

Tags: awk, sed

How do you convert a file like this:

```
ghosts: [[8, 16]]
pacman: [3, 15]
ghosts: [[4, 26]]
pacman: [4,15]
```

to a file like this:

```
ghosts: [[8, 16]], pacman: [3, 15]
ghosts: [[4, 26]], pacman: [4,15]
```

with the sed command?

I tried `sed -e 's/\npac/, pac/g' input_file` and got no change as a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the line break from alternate lines in an ASCII file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412782/how-do-i-remove-the-line-break-from-alternate-lines-in-an-ascii-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge every two lines into one from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/how-to-merge-every-two-lines-into-one-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 'N;s/\n/, /' file
```

Append the next line to the current and replace the newline by a comma followed by a space.

Comment: This one worked perfectly, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{ORS=NR%2?", ":RS}1' file

ghosts: [[8, 16]], pacman: [3, 15]
ghosts: [[4, 26]], pacman: [4,15]
```

or, with `pr`

```
$ pr -2ats', ' file
```

this should be the shortest way!