# Python RegEx remove new lines (that shouldn't be there)

Tags: python, regex

I got some text extracted and wish to clean it up by RegEx.

I have learned basic RegEx but not sure how to build this one:

```
str = '''
this is 
a line that has been cut.
This is a line that should start on a new line
'''
```

should be converted to this:

```
str = '''
this is a line that has been cut.
This is a line that should start on a new line
'''
```

This `r'\w\n\w'` seems to catch it, but not sure how to replace the new line with space and not touch the end and beginning of words

Comment: *Why* should that be the result?  What is the criteria for what newlines get removed (much less how to implement it)?

Comment: if you are in a linux env; 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this lookbehind regex for `re.sub`:

```
>>> str = '''
... this is
... a line that has been cut.
... This is a line that should start on a new line
... '''
>>> print re.sub(r'(?<!\.)\n', '', str)
this is a line that has been cut.
This is a line that should start on a new line
>>>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MsyP5c/1)

`(?<!\.)\n` matches all line breaks that are not preceded by a dot.

If you don't want a match based on presence of dot then use:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\w\s)\n', '', str)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/MsyP5c/2)

Comment: hmm.. can't make it work for the case I have https://repl.it/@Norfeldt/SuperficialCumbersomeTenrec

Comment: That link doesn't even show what is original string. Also note I suggested `r'(?<!\.)\n'` but you have `\w` also in there.

Comment: I know.. sorry.. I thought that my example would cover my use case. It didn't. I had to add `\w`, else it would add some weird places..