# On loading a file in redis, a new line is being inserted in value, how to avoid this

Tags: shell, redis, redis-cli

I am trying to upload a file in redis using command:

```
redis-cli -p <Port> -h <Host> -n <DB> -x set <key> < /tmp/file.json
```

The problem is : in redis value -

It is storing a `\n` at the end of line and I don't want this.

```
"{\"items\":{\"38749\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38712\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"112775\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38721\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38720\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38714\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38726\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38733\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38729\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"113708\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38731\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38745\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38732\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"100074\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38730\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38719\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38723\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38755\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10},\"38760\":{\"buyone\":0,\"buytwo\":10}}}\n"
```

Comment: `tr -d '\n' /tmp/file.json | redis-cli ...`

Answer (score 0):

Since your file contains newlines, that's what gets stored in Redis.

You'll need to strip the newlines from your file **before** setting its contents to Redis. Depending on your OS, the method may vary. Here's a question about this: [How do I remove newlines from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file)

Comment: there was no new line in the file, I checked that many times.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working -

```
cat /tmp/up.json | redis-cli -n 20 --pipe
```

and up.json contents

```
set 'PACKAGES_CONFIG' '{"checkOfferFieldPrices":true,"showPrescInfoScreen":true,"showAddOnsScreen":true,"offerText":"1 + 1 with Lenskart Gold","bannerConfig":{"isVisible":true,"primaryText":"Hi %s, You are a GOLD Member!","secondaryText":"You are eligible for Buy 1 Get 1 offer on this order!"},"isExpandedByDefault":true,"isPreSelected":true,"displayBogoTabs": true, "defaultSelectedTabId": "buy2","tabConfig":[{"id":"buy1","title":"Buy 1","subtitle":"No Offer","enabled":true},{"id":"buy2","title":"Buy 2","subtitle":"Buy 1 Get 1 Free","enabled":true}]}'
```