# Trying to use the line cookbook and it fails with errors

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

Anyone used the Line cookbook --> https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/line

I'm trying to add multiple lines to the rsyslog.conf file and using the line cookbook which was suggested earlier.

Contents of the recipe:

```
replace_or_add "New Lines" do
    path "/etc/rsyslog.conf"
    pattern "# ### end of the forwarding rule ###"
    line "#audit log\n$ModLoad imfile\n$InputFileName /var/log/audit/audit.log\n$InputFileTag tag_audit_log:\n$InputFileStateFile audit_log\n$InputFileSeverity info\n$InputFileFacility local6\n$InputRunFileMonitor\n*.*"
 end
```

It fails with

================================================================================
    Error executing action `edit` on resource 'replace_or_add[New Lines]'
    ================================================================================

```
ArgumentError
-------------
Line #audit log
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/log/audit/audit.log
$InputFileTag tag_audit_log:
$InputFileStateFile audit_log
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local6
$InputRunFileMonitor

 has embedded EOL characters, not allowed for this resource
```

I tried using the tr -d '\n' < yourfile.txt as mentioned in [How do I remove newlines from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file) but it still fails with the same error.
but it still fails with the same eror.

Anyone tested the line cook book for adding multiple lines to a rsysconfig file or even adding multiple lines to a file using this cookbook??

Thank you,
Anish

Answer (score 2):

It's not the file, you have `\n` characters in your `line` value. One line at a time. Try `poise-file` instead probably.

EDIT:

Also, srsly don't do this, like I told you last time. Rsyslog supports things like `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/` which allow pulling config in from multiple discrete files. Use that instead.

Comment: Could you please elaborate "$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/ " I'm unable to figure  it out on how to include config from other files, Is there an example i could refer tooo

Comment: Open up your existing `rsyslog.conf` file. Most of them have an `$IncludeConfig` line by default. So in this case rather than editing the single file, you would use a template or file resource to add your config content to `/etc/rsyslog.d/whatever.conf`. Much simpler :)