# Combine multiple lines into one single line in file using bash

Tags: bash

I would like to combine multiple lines into one single line in file using bash. I tried almost all options mentioned in:
[How do I remove newlines from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file) but no luck and it didn't remove new lines. This file is JSON output from REST API and parsing using bash.

How to combine below lines into 1 line?

File content (actual):

```
{"key":"HAM-5765","status":"Closed","components":"Web UX","affectedVersions":"ZCS 8.8.x","fixVersions":"Konrad-Zuse-8.8.10","customerFacingInfo":"[https://bug.rectify?id=35231 Bug 35231] 
* GetEffectiveRightsRequest failed when a delegated admin could not read zimbraMailHost ([https://bug.rectify?id=108536 Bug 108536])
* Had been unable to remove \"Dynamic Group\" from distribution properties page ([https://bug.rectify?id=108499 Bug 108499])
* After performing a bulk migration, the Delegated Admin user encountered an `HTTP Error 403` when attempting to download the list of provisioned accounts
```

File content (expected):

```
{"key":"HAM-5765","status":"Closed","components":"Web UX","affectedVersions":"ZCS 8.8.x","fixVersions":"Konrad-Zuse-8.8.10","customerFacingInfo":"[https://bug.rectify?id=35231 Bug 35231] * GetEffectiveRightsRequest failed when a delegated admin could not read zimbraMailHost ([https://bug.rectify?id=108536 Bug 108536])* Had been unable to remove \"Dynamic Group\" from distribution properties page ([https://bug.rectify?id=108499 Bug 108499])* After performing a bulk migration, the Delegated Admin user encountered an `HTTP Error 403` when attempting to download the list of provisioned accounts
```

Tried these different commands:

```
tr -d "\n\r" < yourfile.txt
tr -d '\n' < file.txt
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n+//g' input >output
awk '/[0-9]+/ { a = a $0 ";" } END { print a }' file.txt
perl -p -i -e 's/\R//g;' filename
head -n 1 filename | od -c 
perl -pe 's/\s+//g' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: What exactly did not work? `td -d '\n\r'` should work. Could it be, that you expected the file content to change? All of these commands write the processed file to stdout. You have to redirect that output into a new file: `tr -d '\n\r' < inputfile > outputfile`.

Comment: It didn't remove new lines. I tried tr -d '\n\r' < inputfile > outputfile and it just moved one line in outputfile.

Comment: I can neither reproduce nor believe that. What is the output of `tr -d '\n\r' < inputfile | wc -l`? I assume it to be `0`. If so, could it be that you are looking at the file using an editor with word wrapping? Please don't use the file on your hard drive, but *copy* your example from this question to make sure that we are using the same input. If it works with your example but not with your actual file, then post a hexdump of your file.

Comment: It worked fine using: echo -e "${jsonOutput}" >> ${releaseNoteFile}
   rm -f ${releaseNoteDir}/ReleaseNote.tmp
   tr -d '\n\r' < ${releaseNoteFile} > ${releaseNoteDir}/ReleaseNote.tmp
   mv ${releaseNoteDir}/ReleaseNote.tmp ${releaseNoteFile} Please post as answer so i can accept it. Thanks Socowi!

Comment: It's not clear what your problem was or how @Socowi's comments led you to issue the commands you say resolved the issue. If your real question is "how can I replace the original file with a modified file" there are plenty of duplicates of that.

Comment: You can post and accept your own answer. However, I'm with tripleee. Seems more like a combination of two duplicates to me.

Comment: The problem was already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

`cat inputfile | perl -ne 'chomp;print'`

Long version:

```
$ cat inputfile 
{"key":"HAM-5765","status":"Closed","components":"Web UX","affectedVersions":"ZCS 8.8.x","fixVersions":"Konrad-Zuse-8.8.10","customerFacingInfo":"[https://bug.rectify?id=35231 Bug 35231] 
* GetEffectiveRightsRequest failed when a delegated admin could not read zimbraMailHost ([https://bug.rectify?id=108536 Bug 108536])
* Had been unable to remove \"Dynamic Group\" from distribution properties page ([https://bug.rectify?id=108499 Bug 108499])
* After performing a bulk migration, the Delegated Admin user encountered an `HTTP Error 403` when attempting to download the list of provisioned accounts
$ cat inputfile | perl -ne 'chomp;print' > outputfile
$ echo $(cat  outputfile) 
{"key":"HAM-5765","status":"Closed","components":"Web UX","affectedVersions":"ZCS 8.8.x","fixVersions":"Konrad-Zuse-8.8.10","customerFacingInfo":"[https://bug.rectify?id=35231 Bug 35231] 123.html 12a.html 12.html 1.html app-12.html inputfile outputfile GetEffectiveRightsRequest failed when a delegated admin could not read zimbraMailHost ([https://bug.rectify?id=108536 Bug 108536])* Had been unable to remove \"Dynamic Group\" from distribution properties page ([https://bug.rectify?id=108499 Bug 108499])* After performing a bulk migration, the Delegated Admin user encountered an `HTTP Error 403` when attempting to download the list of provisioned accounts
```

Comment: I'd add some explanation/sample input & output at least