# Removing white spaces from a file in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have a file with the following data:

```
2.18521   
3.00948   
4.35773   
5.43936
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
2.18521   3.00948   4.35773   5.43936
```

How can I implement this using the sed or any other command in linux? 
I could use:

```
sed  -i '2.18521      /2.18521/g' file
```

But this does not help since there are many numbers in the file with different numerical values and I cannot go through all of them.

I should add that, the data actually looks like this:

```
     0 0 0 0 0 0
     2.18521   
     3.00948   
     4.35773   
     5.43936
```

And I do not want anything to be done with the numbers above the block.
The output should look like this:

```
     0 0 0 0 0 0
     2.18521   3.00948   4.35773   5.43936
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove newlines from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file)

Comment: I assumed the indenting was one level too high by accident so I fixed it. LMK if I was wrong.

Comment: It partially does, Maybe I should expand more, there are some other numbers in the file that I would not like to touch. 
This command targets the entire file. Is there a way to achieve what I want using a  modification of this command?

Comment: Well what do you want exactly? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @wjandrea Looks more like OP wants to replace newlines with tabs or spaces, not completely strip them.  There's probably a better duplicate.

Comment: @Shawn I thought that too but there's trailing whitespace in the file snippet

Comment: I have edited the question to include more details.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I have included an edit with the desired output.

Comment: Are the leading spaces part of the file?

Comment: Yes. those spaces do not affect the desired output. The main aspect is all the data below "0 0 0 0 0 0" being on the same line.

Comment: Yes. I have done that. 
I am still new to stack overflow hence the naivety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '1b; :a; N; s/\n//; ta' file
```

Output:

```
     0 0 0 0 0 0
     2.18521        3.00948        4.35773        5.43936
```