# How to remove all newlines from all .txt files in a folder, using UNIX tools?

Tags: command-line

I got about 300 (.txt) files in a folder with "normal text" formatted with /n's. I want all text in these files, to be in the first line, because a program in my pipeline requires that.

Exampel:

(IS:)
GTCGCAGCCG
TCGGCTCGGA
TCTCGGCCTC

(SHOULD BE:)
GTCGCAGCCGTCGGCTCGGATCTCGGCCTC

If I could overwrite them all, with file names staying the same, that would be convenient. I don't want to crack out python yet, is there an easy UNIX tool / command line approach?

---

I was here before:
[How do I remove newlines from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file)

But how to do that for all 300 files in my folder? If i use `tr -d '\n' < *.txt` it tells me: "bash: *.txt: ambiguous redirect"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove newlines from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a shell loop to process each file in turn. Note that `ed` is a better choice than `tr`, as it is designed to work with files, not streams.

```
for f in *.txt; do
    printf '%%j\nwq\n' | ed "$f"
done
```

`%j` is the `ed` command to join all lines in the buffer; the `%%` is necessary here to make `printf` output a literal `%`. `wq` is the command to write changes back to the file and quite. (The `q` is optional, as `ed` will exit after the end of its script anyway.)

Comment: From what i can see this seems to work. Thx (: